# MATLAB: How to vectorize the accumulation of complex conjugates?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm learning how to use a MATLAB script for SENSE MRI reconstruction, and one of the sections goes as follows:

```
% Form high-res brain image by combining the image data from all coil
% channels.  This is done by multiplying each channel image elementwise by
% its complex conjugate, accumulating into the high-res image, and taking
% the square root of the result (since multplying by a complex conjugate
% results in obtaining the square of the real part)

for k = 1:nchannels
    Image_E = Image_E + Img(:, :, k).*conj(Img(:, :, k));
end
Image_E = sqrt(Image_E);
```

`Img` is a 256x256x8 array, where the third dimension is composed of a "stack" of eight complex-valued brain images.  Each pixel of `Image_E` is the l-2 norm of the absolute values of the corresponding pixel from each of the 8 images in the `Img` stack.

I suspect that there is a more efficient, vectorized way to implement the routine performed above (perhaps using `arrayfun()`) but no solid implementations have so far come to mind.

Comment: `arrayfun` is about as efficient as a `for` loop, not more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are multiplying complex conjugates then it is the same as Real.^2+Img.^2, therefore a simpler way would be

```
Image_E=sqrt(sum(real(Img).^2+imag(Img).^2,3))
```